# Omitting parantheses in formulas

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Lately I read the following:

> parentheses can always be omitted, so instead of $((\neg A)\Rightarrow B)$ we may write $(\neg A)\Rightarrow B$. But we may not write $\neg A\Rightarrow B$, because this would not distinguish the intended formula from $\neg(A\Rightarrow B)$.

I understand why the outermost parantheses may be omitted but I don't understand why the omission of the inner parantheses around $A$ does not distinguish the formula from the last formula stated in the picture. I tried to reason as to why they would not be distinguished from each other and all I could come up with was that it's probably an aesthetic rather than a structural reason.

Comment: The point is that when you write $\lnot A \Rightarrow B$, it is not clear [without specifying operator precedence] whether it is intended to mean $(\lnot A) \Rightarrow B$ or $\lnot (A\Rightarrow B)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer But how exactly would one specify operator precedence (I'm fairly new to propositional calculus)?

Comment: Like in programming languages. You make a table listing which operator binds tighter than which. Or if you want something more rigorous, you make a grammar. And henceforth everybody gets the precedence wrong now and again.

Comment: "And henceforth everybody gets the precedence wrong now and again. "

That seems like a repeated pattern of errors which are avoidable by using prefix or postfix notation.

Comment: Note the questions here confusing $-(x^2)$ with $(-x)^2$ when $-x^2$ is written.  Of course in this case, only beginners make the mistake.

Comment: Parentheses in logic formulas can become very numerous.  Some older logic texts set up a system of dots to use in place of parentheses.

Comment: @GEdgar A particular older logic text used dots to stand both for conjunction and to work like parentheses.  I started reading it and basically stopped reading it when I found that ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of this is a matter of [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) (or operator precedence).
For instance, this is carefully defined in any programming language.

From the same wikipedia article:
In logic, $\neg$ has higher precedence than $\wedge$, $\wedge$ higher than $\vee$, and $\vee$ higher than $\rightarrow$.

Comment: The $\neg$ operator (and prefix operators in general) have precedence for right to left, e.g.  $\neg\neg\neg P \equiv \neg(\neg(\neg P))$.

Comment: Binary operators usually have precedence from left to right. Occasional exception: ^ operator for exponentiation. Usually 2^3^4 $\equiv$ (2^3)^4. Sometimes 2^3^4 $\equiv$ 2^(3^4). If exponentiation indicated by superscripts, then precedence is from right to left, e.g. $2^{3^4}\equiv 2^{(3^4)}$.

Answer (score 3):

It ought to be clear that it's unworkable to allow omitting the parentheses in *both* $(\neg A)\Rightarrow B$ and $\neg(A\Rightarrow B)$. These are two different formulas with different meanings, yet *each* of them becomes "$\neg A\Rightarrow B$" if we omit the parentheses.

Thus, in order to be sure what we're speaking about we need *either* to declare that "$\neg A\Rightarrow B$" is not a legal way to write a formula, *or* agree on some convention for which of $(\neg A)\Rightarrow B$ or $\neg(A\Rightarrow B)$ it is going to mean.

The quote that confuses you describes situation *before such a convention has been set*.

Once you *have* decided to use the common convention, $\neg A\Rightarrow B$ is going to mean $(\neg A)\Rightarrow B$. But it is important to be aware that there *is* a choice being made and that we could equally well (from a formal point of view) have chosen the opposite convention for writing down things. That's just not the *common* choice.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the main issue here (one that used to bother me as well) concerns *operator precedence*. As Henning notes, a *convention* has to be established first for anything to make sense and to avoid ambiguity. Broadly speaking, the following is a little table that lists binary connectives and their corresponding *ranks*:
\begin{array}{ccc}
\hline
{} & \text{Rank of Operators} & {}\\
\hline
\text{Operator}& {} & \text{Rank}\\
\hline
\Large\leftrightarrow & {} & 5\\[0.5em]
\Large\rightarrow & {} & 4\\[0.5em]
\Large\lor & {} & 3\\[0.5em]
\Large\land & {} & 2\\[0.5em]
\Large\neg & {} & 1\\
\hline
\end{array}
With these rankings in mind, a simple process may be used to determine how to eliminate parentheses. The following description of this process may appear to be somewhat complicated at first, but its simplicity will be illustrated with a few examples.

---

**Examples:** As examples, we will consider
$$
Q \rightarrow R \rightarrow \neg S \land \neg T \lor U \leftrightarrow V \land W \land X \lor Y\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
[(Q \lor R) \leftrightarrow S] \rightarrow [(\neg T) \land U].\tag{2}
$$

---

Suppose we encounter the propositional form $\Upsilon \, \phi \, \Lambda$, where $\Upsilon$ and $\Lambda$ may be statement letters or propositional forms with several components, and $\phi$ is one of the connectives, $\leftrightarrow, \rightarrow, \lor, \text{or } \land$. The outermost parentheses, if any, are dropped from $\Upsilon$ if the rank of $\phi$ is greater than or equal to the rank of $\Upsilon$. The outermost parentheses, if any, are dropped from $\Lambda$ if the rank of $\phi$ is greater than the rank of $\Lambda$. This process is repeated until parentheses can no longer be dropped.

Any difficulties encountered while trying to understand the finer points of how the process works should be put to rest by seeing how the process is used to add parentheses to $(1)$ and remove parentheses from $(2)$. If we let $\rho$ and $\sigma$ represent $(2)$ and $(1)$, respectively, then we may use the process to get
\begin{align}
 \rho  &\Leftrightarrow  [(Q \lor R) \leftrightarrow S] \rightarrow [(\neg T) \land U] \nonumber  \\[0.5em]
  &\Leftrightarrow [(Q \lor R) \leftrightarrow S] \rightarrow (\neg T) \land U \nonumber \\[0.5em]
  &\Leftrightarrow  [Q \lor R \leftrightarrow S] \rightarrow (\neg T) \land U \nonumber \\[0.5em]
  &\Leftrightarrow (Q \lor R \leftrightarrow S) \rightarrow \neg T \land U  \nonumber  
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
 \sigma  &\Leftrightarrow Q \rightarrow R \rightarrow \neg S \land \neg T \lor U \leftrightarrow V \land W \land X \lor Y   \nonumber \\[0.5em]
   &\Leftrightarrow [Q \rightarrow R \rightarrow \neg S \land \neg T \lor U] \leftrightarrow [V \land W \land X \lor Y] \nonumber \\[0.5em]
   &\Leftrightarrow [(Q \rightarrow R) \rightarrow (\neg S \land \neg T \lor U)] \leftrightarrow [V \land W \land X \lor Y]  \nonumber \\[0.5em]
   &\Leftrightarrow  [(Q \rightarrow R) \rightarrow ((\neg S \land \neg T) \lor U)] \leftrightarrow [(V \land W \land X) \lor Y] \nonumber \\[0.5em]
   &\Leftrightarrow  [(Q \rightarrow R) \rightarrow ((\neg S \land \neg T) \lor U)] \leftrightarrow [((V \land W) \land X) \lor Y] \nonumber \\[0.5em]
   &\Leftrightarrow  [(Q \rightarrow R) \rightarrow (((\neg S) \land (\neg T)) \lor U)] \leftrightarrow [((V \land W) \land X) \lor Y]. \nonumber
\end{align}

---

As you can see, those are rather heady examples. You can get as fine-detailed as you want, but the main point to keep in mind when communicating mathematics is to strike a balance between clarity and brevity. From the examples above, it is clear that it would be perfectly valid to simply write
$$
Q \rightarrow R \rightarrow \neg S \land \neg T \lor U \leftrightarrow V \land W \land X \lor Y,
$$
but what reader is going to be able to parse that effectively?

Using the method outlined above, you can choose for yourself, more or less, just *how many* parentheses you chose to include or exclude, but always remember that clarity is a must.

If you'd like, you can read where most of this post came from--an "article" I wrote a few years back. It may be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ty3brvfsuo5lfd3/Chaotic%20Delimiters%20-%20Some%20Parenthetical%20Advice%20%28Informal%20Introduction%29.pdf?dl=0).